# Polymorphic unique_ptr class member

Tags: c++, polymorphism, unique-ptr

I would like to have a unique_ptr class member that points to the base class, but later in the constructor through polymorphism can be changed to point to a sister class that also derives from the same base class.

While I don't get any errors in the constructor setting this polymorphism, it does not seem to work correctly, since I get error messages that my polymorphic pointer can't find a member of the sister class to which I thought the pointer was now pointing.

How do I correctly achieve polymorphism here?

```
class A {
  int bar;
};

class B : public A {
  int foo;
};

class C: public A {
  C();

  std::unique_ptr<A> _ptr; // changing to std::unique_ptr<B> _ptr removes the "class A has no member 'foo'" error
};

C::C() : A()
{
  _ptr = std::make_unique<B>(); // no errors here
  int w = _ptr->foo; // class A has no member 'foo'
}
```

Comment: What exactly surprises you here? `_ptr` points to an `A`. The class `A` does not have a member `foo`.

Comment: There is no polymorphism here, only inheritance.

Comment: And you have UB, as you destroy B as A without virtual destructor.

Comment: If you just need to use the foo member here, you need some casting.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign

```
_ptr = std::make_unique<B>();
```

This works because `B` is a derived class of `A`, however `_ptr` is still a `unique_ptr` to the base class. You can't change the type of a variable after it's declared.

So what are your options?

Because you know that `_ptr` stores a pointer to the derived class `B`, you can do a cast after dereferencing it:

```
_ptr = std::make_unique<B>(); 
// derefence the pointer, and cast the reference to `B&`. 
B& reference_to_sister = (B&)(*_ptr);
int w = reference_to_sister.foo;
```

If you take this approach, you'll have to somehow keep track of which derived class is in `_ptr`, or you'll run the risk of running into bugs.

Alternatively, if you're using C++17, you can use `std::variant`:

```
class C : public A {
  void initialize(A& a) {
      // Do stuff if it's the base class
  }
  void initialize(B& b) {
      // Do different stuff if it's derived
      int w = b.foo; 
  }
  C() {
      _ptr = std::make_unique<B>(); // This works
      // This takes the pointer, and calls 'initialize'
      auto initialize_func = [&](auto& ptr) { initialize(*ptr); };
      // This will call 'initialize(A&)' if it contains A,
      // and it'll call 'initialize(B&)' if it contains B
      std::visit(initialize_func, _ptr); 
  }

  std::variant<std::unique_ptr<A>, std::unique_ptr<B>> _ptr;
};
```

In fact, if you use `std::variant` this will work even if `A` and `B` are completely unrelated classes.

Here's another short `variant` example

```
#include <variant>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void print(std::string& s) {
    std::cout << "String: " << s << '\n';
}
void print(int i) {
    std::cout << "Int: " << i << '\n'; 
}

void print_either(std::variant<std::string, int>& v) {
    // This calls `print(std::string&) if v contained a string
    // And it calls `print(int)` if v contained an int
    std::visit([](auto& val) { print(val); }, v); 
}

int main() {
    // v is empty right now
    std::variant<std::string, int> v;

    // Put a string in v:
    v = std::string("Hello, world"); 
    print_either(v); //Prints "String: Hello, world"

    // Put an int in v:
    v = 13; 
    print_either(v); //Prints "Int: 13"
}
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! I was getting polymorphism confused with casting.

Comment: Sure thing! Lemme know if you have any other questions or issues